# Github hooks: creating a branch triggers both create and push

Tags: git, github, githooks, webhooks

I have configured a couple of github webhooks for working with my team:

1. One for when a member of the team pushes to a branch
2. Another one for when someone on the team creates a new branch

The problem is with (2); After I create a new branch like below:

```
git checkout -b test master
git push -u origin test
```

both `create` **and** `push` hooks are triggered. However in this case I only need `create` to be triggered. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

My hooks are the following:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "active": true,
  "events": [
    "create"
  ],
  "config": {
    "url": "http://myurl/create",
    "content_type": "json"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "active": true,
  "events": [
    "push"
  ],
  "config": {
    "url": "http://myurl/push",
    "content_type": "json"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else out there wondering how to solve this:

It seems that the hook payload includes a `created` field which tells you whether the ref was created as a result of the push. In other words if its value is true the push event was triggered as a result of the branch creation (that's how we push it to the remote anyway).

Otherwise it's just a plain code push.

Filter it on your end and you're good to go.